# select nearest row based on search text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me to make below select query in SQL server

source table

```
Name    
-------
A   
B   
F   
L   
Y
```

if search key=A
select row a

if search key=E (if no text match then take the nearest row)
select row F

Comment: Define _nearest_: is "Y" nearer to "X" or "Z"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick using `ASCII` & `ABS` function.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   (VALUES ('A'),
               ('B'),
               ('F'),
               ('L'),
               ('Y')) tc (NAME)
ORDER  BY Abs(Ascii(NAME) - Ascii('E')) -- Pass the input here
```

**Result :** `F`

To do this in your table

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM   Yourtable
ORDER  BY Abs(Ascii(NAME) - Ascii('E')) -- Pass the input here
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The values A,B etc are rows in a table

Comment: @Manuv - Replace the table valued constructor with your table. For showing demo I have used it. Updated my answer